Why cant my sprite image display on the browser when the same sprite without transparent pixels or reduced size will?
Okay this is quite a long question but i will try to sum it up.
I have made a simple html, css and javascript code. The JS tracks the amount of scroll trought the webpage and it is linked to the css so the css will animate a sprite image only when you are scrolling. The sprite image is actually an animation i made in blender, exported it as a png sequence, converted it into a GIF with After Effects and then made it into a big sprite (78016px by 1000px). Now here is the catch...when i render the animation with the viewport visibility (which means there are NO transparent pixels) it works fine, BUT when i render the image with all the textures applied on the model and where the background is transparent it wont display on the page. The 2 images are the same dimensions except 1 has transparency. As soon as i half the dimension of the sprite it works...but i need it bigger. I have tried everything i could and i have googled a lot and i cant figure it out. I will place the codes down below.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <div></div>
    <h1>ALOOOOOOOOOO</h1>
    
</body>
</html>

div {
    width: 736px; 
    height: 1000px;   
    background: url("test2.png");
    
    animation: kocka 1s steps(106) infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-delay: calc(var(--scroll) * -1s);
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    
    
    

}

@keyframes kocka {
    0%{background-position: 0 0;}
    100%{background-position: -78016px 0;}
}

body {
    height: 20000px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 400%;
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    document.body.style.setProperty('--scroll', window.pageYOffset / (document.body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight));
  }, false);

These are the the viewport PNGs so you have in mind what im talking about. I could send the sprites if needed but they are huge.
[[enter image description here](enter image description here)](https://i.sstatic.net/TZN6V.png)
I have every css element that has something to do with backgrounds and nothing helped.
